# Pipe into case with named parameter

Tags: elixir

What would the syntax be fore piping into a case statement and using the piped parameter? I can't seem to find it anywhere. I have two "ideas" but i don't know which would be correct, if either.

```
something
|> do_something()
|> case do
  nil -> {:error, "ITS REAL NIL"}
  %MyStruct{} -> Methods.next_something(&1.attrib)
  _ -> {:error, "NAH BRUH. THE WEIRD HAPPENED."}
```

```
something
|> do_something()
|> case do
  nil -> {:error, "ITS REAL NIL"}
  struct = %MyStruct{} -> Methods.next_something(struct.attrib)
  _ -> {:error, "NAH BRUH. THE WEIRD HAPPENED."}
```

Comment: That's correct, just add the `end`

Comment: since you cannot use &1 outside of a capture, the second one seems more correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question itself reveals your fundamental misunderstanding of what `do` block is in a nutshell.

[`Kernel.SpecialForms.case/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html?#case/2) accepts two parameters: `condition` *and* `clauses`. And `do ... end` syntax is nothing but syntactic sugar to `do: ...` keyword list parameter, inlined by compiler.

When you have a function of arity 2, you don’t hesitate to use pipe operator to pass the first parameter there, leaving the second intact. `do ... end` block is simply that second parameter.

Consider the following code:

```rb
case :ok, do: (:ok -> 42; _ -> nil)    
#⇒ 42
```

The above is equivalent to

```rb
case(:ok, [do: (:ok -> 42; _ -> nil)])
#⇒ 42
```

Now we evidently see two parameters, the first being of type `term()` and the second being a keyword list. That’s it.

Hence there cannot be any captured parameter: we have no capture, we have a regular call (to a macro `case`.)

That said, your second approach is correct.

Answer (score 0):

This should work...

```
something
|> do_something()
|> case do
  nil -> {:error, "ITS REAL NIL"}
  %MyStruct{atrib: atrib} -> Methods.next_something(atrib)
  _ -> {:error, "NAH BRUH. THE WEIRD HAPPENED."}
end
```

Comment: Although it answers the question stated, the answer itself is of very poor quality, barely explaining whats and whys.

Answer (score 0):

Pipe isn't relevant to the question. This will work:

```rb
case %{foo: "bar"} do
  map = %{} -> {:success, map.foo}
end
```

But it's clearer and better practice to match the values on the left that you want to use on the right:

```rb
case %{foo: "bar"} do
  %{foo: foo} -> {:success, foo}
end
```

Comment: How does it answer the question stated?

Comment: IMO it's an XY question and the OP is really asking how pattern matching works in a case statement, so I demonstrated that (which is useful, as opposed to not useful, as the downvote would suggest). Whether pipe is used or not is not relevant to how matching works. To be honest, I'm not sure why the OP didn't just try to compile the two versions.